# Layout page with downloaded layout template not rendering properly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-5

I created a new ASP .Net MVC 5 project with all the sample views, controllers and such. It has the latest versions of jQuery and Bootstrap.

So I wanted to have a nice template on it so I downloaded [this one](http://oswd.co/preview/metamorph_highway/) and I added the images and css files to the content folder, modified the BundleConfig class so that the new css file is included and also changed _ViewStart.cshtml file so that it takes the new layout which I named _myLayout.cshtml.

Technically it worked very well since all the pages now use the new layout template but it is not rendering properly, the menu looks truncated, the header image and the content section are going outside of the border on the right side, and the footer is displayed with a margin at the bottom which should not exist.

I have been able to pinpoint the problem to a "collision" between the template's css and bootstrap since if I remove the bootstrap stylesheet from the BundleConfig file and then styles got rendered as expected.

I am more of a backend/javascript developer so my knowledge about css is very limited and I am way over my head with this one. So much that I don't even know which code to include and both css files are too large to include them in the question.

If anyone is able to help I would really appreciate it and/or if someone can provide some clues as to which css sections would be useful to include in the post to help pinpoint the problem please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**

To replicate the problem you would have to:
- Download [the template I mentioned above](http://oswd.co/preview/metamorph_highway/)
- Create a new ASP .Net MVC 5 project
- Add the images and styles.css file from the template on the project's content folder
- On the project's Shared folder create a new layout page called _myLayout.cshtml
- Do the following changes on these files:

BundleConfig.cs

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Optimization;

namespace SC.Web
{
    public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                      "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                      "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css",
                      "~/Content/styles.css"));
        }
    }
}
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_myLayout.cshtml";
}
```

_myLayout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="description" content="" />
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <!-- start header -->
        <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                <h1><a href="#">metamorph_highway</a></h1>
                <h2><a href="http://www.metamorphozis.com/" id="metamorph">Design by Metamorphosis Design</a></h2>
            </div>
            <div id="menu">
                <ul>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- end header -->
        </div>
        <hr />
        <!-- start page -->
        <div id="page">
            <!-- start content -->
            <div id="content">
                @RenderBody()
            </div>
            <!-- end content -->
            <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
        <!-- end page -->
        <hr />
        <!-- start footer -->
        <div id="footer">
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
            <p>Copyright &copy; 2008. <a href="#">Privacy Policy</a> | <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> | <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check/referer" title="This page validates as XHTML 1.0 Transitional"><abbr title="eXtensible HyperText Markup Language">XHTML</abbr></a> | <a href="http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" title="This page validates as CSS"><abbr title="Cascading Style Sheets">CSS</abbr></a></p>
            <p>
                Design by <a href="http://www.metamorphozis.com/" title="Free Site Templates">Free Site Templates</a>, coded by <a href="http://www.flashtemplatesdesign.com" title="Free Flash Templates">Free Flash Templates</a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- end footer -->
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have a great description, but because there is no code to review, this question is unanswerable.  Always provide your code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips That's the best I can do with the knowledge I have :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that on bootstrap there is this definition:

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Since the template I downloaded gets messed up with this I added the following on its own css file:

```
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

I have no idea if later this will cause bootstrap not to behave as it should and if that happens I'll have to deal with that then.